# Acceleo and Hibernate

Tags: acceleo

Does Acceleo generate Hibernate or is it UML2 to Java EE that does that? if Acceleo is doing it, then can someone please guide me to a sample example for it that generates Hibernate.

Also I want to know if either one of Acceleo or UML2 to Java EE generate Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Acceleo is a generic code generator, you can create an Acceleo based generator to generate anything from assembly to Ruby if you want. You can find online some Acceleo generators that I have created in order to generate [Java from UML](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Java-Generation) or [Scala from a custom Scala metamodel](https://github.com/sbegaudeau/acceleo-modules/tree/master/psm-gen-scala). If you want to generate Java EE, you can create a Java EE generator by using the UML to Java generator as an inspiration.

Currently we are working on the new version of Obeo Designer for IS which contains Acceleo 3 based generator to generate Spring/Struts/Hibernate from our three custom metamodels ([entities, cinematic and soa](http://obeo.fr/pages/obeo-designer-for-is/demonstration/en)). OD4IS is a commercial product built on top of Acceleo (which is free and open source). You can find more about OD4IS on our [website](http://obeo.fr/pages/obeo-designer-for-is/en). I don't have the release date for this new version of OD4IS but it should be available in the upcoming weeks. In the mean time, you can create your own generators or give the previous version of OD4IS a try (an evaluation version is available online). It should be noted that this previous version is based on Acceleo 2.x.

**Disclaimer: I am working at Obeo as a developer on both Acceleo and OD4IS**